# Javascript function only alert Me

Tags: javascript

this is my Javascript function for check 2 passwords:

```
function isPassEquels(){
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("passReg");
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("passConfReg");
        if(pass1!=pass2)
        {
            alert("don't match");

        }
```

but this only give me alert message and dont stop servlet to executing . How to stop servlet when i get alert message???

Comment: Your code executes at the client, this has nothing to do with server side code (jsp/servlets)

Answer (score 2):

Try `return false;` from within the if statement.

```
    if(pass1.value != pass2.value)
    {
        alert("don't match");
        return false; // Abort
    }
```

Also as @Lloyd said, check for values, not elements.

Comment: I tried but still don't working

Comment: @Krasimir: You don't provide enough information in your question to give you a proper solution. Please edit your question and explain/show how `isPassEquels` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you're comparing page elements and not values, which will always be false. Try this:

```
function isPassEquels(){
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("passReg").value;
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("passConfReg").value;

        if(pass1 != pass2) {
            alert("don't match");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use elements value and `return false` when condition meets

```
function isPassEquels(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("passReg").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("passConfReg").value;

    if(pass1 != pass2) {
        alert("don't match");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to compare element values instead of comparing page elements (like in your code). Another point is use **return false** in your code where you are calling **isPassEquels**. Basically the default return type for a function is true.

So try using the function call as "return isPassEquels()" and compare element values like above examples.

```
function isPassEquels(){
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("passReg");
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("passConfReg");
        if(pass1!=pass2)
        {
            alert("don't match");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach this function to onSubmit event of form and if this function returns false, form will not be submitted.

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return isPassEquels()" method="post">
```

Comment: This + missed values and working thanks a lot Rene